# Object detection using Kinect V2

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox

I know that object detection is not possible using Kinect v1. We need to use 3rd party libraries like open CV or pointclouds (pcl).

But was just curious to know does can it be achived using Kinect v2? Has anyone done any work on it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [<strike>project</strike>](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Kinect--OpenCV--WPF--Blob-Tracking) and use google with `blob detection` keyword.

Comment: this also uses Open CV

Comment: yes, but I don't think that it could be achieved without such library

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that object detection using the Kinect V2 is possible in two ways, but there isn't much by way of complete solutions out there right now (Nov. 2014) because of how new it is and because it hasn't been hacked yet. Currently, I am trying to implement PCL on Windows 8 with visual studio 2012, which are the bare minimum req.s for Kinect v2, and I will keep posted so that you can know how it goeshttp://cs.unc.edu/~kwaegel/pcl/pcl_build_notes.htmlRealistically, the fastest approach would likely be using the v2 SDK (sorry about the link above, don't have enough reputation to share more than 2 links, needed to think of a clever way to get it to you without StackExchange recognizing it as a link :P ). In a brief search I found that this guy acquired the color point clouds from the kinect v2 and was able to output them:

http://laht.info/kinect-v2-colored-point-clouds/

After that, you should be able to segment the point clouds with previous open source software by simply importing your newly acquired point cloud!

http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/random_sample_consensus.php

again, haven't gotten all of these moving parts working together in one environment yet, but it is definitely possible